# Rubik's Cube with a missing color

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, rubiks-cube

Suppose a color of the Rubik's cube(3x3) is missing, is it possible to find the missing color? Now a brute force method would be solve for all other colors, but that is quite naive.

Comment: Just look at the cube and notice which color is missing. Do you mean something else?

Comment: Would the answer be different for a 4x4 cube?

Comment: Gregory Grant, I don't know, but I have a hunch that it might be.

Comment: count all colored squares, the one which does not add up to 9?

Comment: When you say that "a color is missing", do you mean that a single sticker is missing, or that all the (say) orange stickers are missing? In the latter case, the pieces where the stickers are missing will all show the raw plastic the cube is made of, which is usually a different color from any of the stickers -- so you can just solve the cube normally. But obviously you cannot see from the cube whether the 9 missing stickers were orange or purple, for example.